# List having different data to be displayed in excel

Tags: java, excel, list, arraylist, aspose

I have a list of quest id like 1,2,3,4,5,6 for one person id say 34512 and only 4 for other person id say 23124 .I am display the data for each person id in excel like

```
       A  B C D E F --->cells
34512  1  2 3 4 5 6
23124         4
```

i want to show the output as above but i am getting like

```
       A  B C D E F --->cells
34512  1  2 3 4 5 6
23124  4
```

because i am taking the cell count as A to start with for every new person id.I need to see now if the quesid is not present for a given person id then it should leave the cell blank and should display as shown in first .

Can i do anything with list of quesid for previous and new and check if quesid is not present in its list then start the count accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

You should insert empty cells for the questid not present for a person id.

I guess, you are only inserting one cell for person id 23124. but you should insert 3 empty cells first, then a cell with contents and 2 more empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to add person's data at a particular row that matches his id and his quest ids in particular columns that matches his quest ids.

For person id 7, you will like to add his data in row 7 and if his quest id is 1, you will like to insert it in column A and if his quest id is 2, then you will like to enter it column B and so on so forth.

If that is true, then the following code illustrates how to achieve such a thing.

**Java**

```
//Suppose your person id is 7, so your data will be inserted in row 7
int personId = 7;

//Suppose that person's data is 5, then it will be inserted in column E (A, B, C, D, E, F, G...)
int personData = 5;

Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

Worksheet worksheet = workbook.getWorksheets().get(0);

String cellName = CellsHelper.cellIndexToName(personId - 1, personData - 1);

worksheet.getCells().get(cellName).putValue(personData);

workbook.save("output.xlsx", SaveFormat.XLSX);
```

---

I have attached screenshot of output file for your reference.
[image]